# Remote Desktop Redirected Printer Not Showing Printer Preferences

Tags: printing, remote-desktop, virtual-desktop

we are using Remote Desktop to connect to Azure Virtual Desktops.  In the RDP options we enable Printers under the Local Resources tab.  This has worked well for a while and users are able to print using the locally installed printers on the client running RDP.  A feature that always worked until recently is when users go to print, they could click properties on the print dialog and it would display the printer preferences.  This has stopped working and we are not sure why.  Now when users click Properties a couple of errors show up.  They say:
Printing Preferences - The printer has been redirected by the Remote Desktop Connection client.
The printing preferences for the client printer will automatically display in a separate window, where you can review your settings or make changes.
Sorry, you can't change printer properties.
To change these properties, open Remote Desktop Connection on the desktop and connect to .

Our desktops are running Windows 10 or 11 and the AVD is running Windows 11.  It happens for all printers regardless of manufacturer or printer driver.  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is only happening when using the Azure Virtual Desktop app that is available through the Microsoft Store.  Reverting back to the Remote Desktop Connection application that is already installed with Windows resolves the issue.  Guessing eventually the AVD app will work as well but for now will use RDC.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).